# Can I skip an airport and go to the next airport to board a 2-stop flight?

Tags: air-travel, paris, brussels

I am going to Paris. I have a direct flight there (YYZ-CDG) but on the way back it is a 2-stop flight (CDG-BRU-YUL-YYZ). Could I just miss the flight at CDG and drive or take a train to Brussels and start my flight there? The time is much better as I won't have to wake up earlier and I get to go to Brussels.

Comment: The answer is no, you cannot.

Comment: Or rather the answer is it can't hurt to ask the airline if they'll let you do that, but it is nearly certain that they will refuse.  I have personal experience with this.

Comment: Or rather the answer is: of course you can, you just have to pay a re-booking, change, cancellation, surcharge fee etc. If they airline sees any chance to squeeze more money out of you, they will go for it.